# Unable to access other functions of controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am unable to access other functions in my controllers until i add `index.php?` to the url. I can access the `index()` functions of any controller directly but not the other functions. i have checked other related questions but problem persists. i have also tried adding all controllers to `routes.php` but still fails.

HTACESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|include|style\.css|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

CONFIG

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

BLOG CONTROLLER

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['page_name'] = 'blog';
        $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
    }

    public function news()
    {
        $data['page_name'] = 'news';
        $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
    }
}
```

URL

```
   http://localhost/tsb/blog // This works fine
    http://localhost/tsb/blog/news // only works when i add index.php? to the url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check your css and js includes properly. Make sure to use absolute url. From your question you seem to be loading all your views through one index file in (pages) folder

Your assets or resource links should be like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" src="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />
```

Do same for javascript or other assets

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/tsb/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

 $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|include|style\.css|robots\.txt) RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This way all your pages will load properly including all the functions in your controller

Comment: Thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

change from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/tsb/';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';

$config['base_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: update your question and place what you have done in all file

Comment: I did the update as you guided but still failed. I will just start a new install

Answer (score 0):

Find the following:

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

In some cases the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly. Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

This will remove index.php from your URL and you can access pages, methods etc without index.php